# Is there an emacs read-only cline?

Tags: emacs, readonly

Is there an emacs option to read-only a file from command line?
I am looking for something like `vim -R filename`.
  Best.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/204236/how-can-i-open-a-file-read-only-from-command-line-with-emacs-vi-vim

Answer (score 1):

```
emacs FILE --eval '(setq buffer-read-only t)'
```

https://superuser.com/questions/204236/how-can-i-open-a-file-read-only-from-command-line-with-emacs-vi-vim